# ALT key in Eagle (Linux)

Tags: eaglecad, linux

I am facing an annoying problem while using Eagle in Linux.
It is not possible to set the desired position of a component while ALT key is pressed. I hit the ALT key to active the alternate grid and then specify more precisely the correct position.
I also tried to move the component while ALT is pressed, then release the key and left-click to set the position, but then the component moves to the main grid automatically.

I know there is other ways to solve this tricky bug during component placement, but it would be easier using this shortcut. Does someone have already faced this bug?

Thanks,
(I am using Linux Mint with Cinnamon.)

Comment: This question is better suited for eagle support, mailing list, or bug report

Comment: Are you clicking with the ALT button pressed? Or are you locating it with the ALT button and then release it and then click it. Because it needs to be set on the alternate grid before adjusting it on that alternate grid.

Comment: I've tried both, @Weaverworm.

Answer (score 2):

EAGLE interferes with your operating system settings.
I'm using OpenSuse with KDE5 Plasma, where `ALT + mouseclick` resizes or moves the window. EAGLE may notice the `ALT` key is pressed, but a click is intercepted by Linux.

Just try to remove the `ALT + mouseclick` key binding. As every linux differs a little, I can't tell you how exactly to do it. For me, it's in `workspace settings / window behaviour`.

Answer (score 2):

In KDE Plasma 5 it can be disabled by:

System settings -> Window management -> Window behavior -> Windows Actions

You can change the modifier key or disable the left button action.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me in order to solve this bug in Linux Mint with Cinnamon:

System Settings>Windows>Moving and Resizing Windows> "Special keys to move and resize windows: Disabled"